# нужно удалить все числа оканчивающиеся на 5 (например, 5, 15, 25 и тд)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def five(num):
    num_list = list(range(1, num+1))
    num_odds = []
    for i in num_list:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            num_odds.append(i)
        for j in num_odds:
            if j*5 == i:
                num_list.remove(i)
    return num_list

print(five(17))
```

Метод заключается в том, что число, оканчивающееся на 5 это нечетное * 5.
Мне нужно сделать, чтобы числа удалялись в диапазоне от num1 до num2. Код, где нет диапазона работает нормально, но при добавлении ничего не происходит:

```
def five(num1,num2):
    num_list = list(range(num1, num2+1))
    num_odds = []
    for i in num_list:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            num_odds.append(i)
        for j in num_odds:
            if j*5 == i:
                num_list.remove(i)
    return num_list

print(five(4,17))
```

Comment: Совет: вместо этой малопонятной мешанины циклов применить простой прямолинейный алгоритм. Что, например, делает проверка ``if j*5 == i``?

Comment: и что вообще такое "число, оканчивающееся на 5 это нечетное * 5. "?

Comment: if j*5 == i #проверка, при которой нечетное число, у множенное на 5 равно числу в общем списке (j - это число из "нечетного списка". А число, оканчивающееся на 5 это, к примеру, 5 * 1, 5 * 3, 5 * 5 и тд., то есть нечетное на 5. У меня проблема в работе всей этой конструкции при добавлении диапазонов - она отказывается работать

Answer (score 1):

```
Может так?

def function(array):
    new_array = [integer for integer in array if not str(integer).endswith('5')]
    return new_array

test_array = [25, 46, 5, 35, 97, 144, 255]


print(function(test_array))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Обращайтесь:-).

Comment: def test(num1,num2):
    arr_list = list(range(num1, num2+1))
    new_array = [integer for integer in arr_list if not str(integer).endswith('5')]
    return new_array
print(test(4,17))

Конечный вариант, может кому пригодится

Answer (score 0):

```
# simple
def five(start, end):
    result = filter(lambda x: x % 10 == 5, range(start, end + 1))
    return list(result)


# faster
def five2(start, end):
    result = list()
    value = start
    while value <= end:
        if value % 10 == 5:
            result.append(value)
            value += 10
        else:
            value += 1

    return result
```